# Why is a div called a div? Why is a span called a span?

Tags: html

My assumption is that div means "divider" because it divides elements (due to the new line before and after), and that span is called span because it's inline, so it "spans" its content. Was it ever directly indicated where they came up with these names?

Comment: It's weird, because inline elements do not span their containing block. Blocks do.

Comment: Blocks don't span, they appear to span because of the newlines that are implicitly inserted... I think. Whereas spans do truly span their contents... I think. For instance, if you float two divs, they will appear next to each other.

Comment: spans don't span the document. they're only as wide as their contents.

Comment: You're right actually... so semantically it makes no sense.

Comment: It seems DIV was introduced in [HTML 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#div), where it says: *"DIV elements can be used to structure HTML documents as a hierarchy of divisions."* SPAN seems to have been introduced in HTML 4, but it's not clear why that name was chosen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, because I don't see how it's a "programming problem" or how the answers to the question might solve such a question. Obviously, this is merely my own opinion, though.

Comment: @DavidThomas Can't disagree. It's an interesting question though. The span part especially has no answer apparently. I'd have to actually email the writers of the standard to find out.

Comment: It doesn't explain the origin of the name, but if you are interested in the history of `span`, see https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/span#History

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[According to HTML 3.2 reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#block) `<div>` stands for "document divisions".

`<span>` simply comes from the related verb.
The physically written `<span>` and `</span>` tags span their content. One before, one after. They do nothing more, have no semantic use, no meaning, and are generics, which could explain such a name. For another example, it could have been `<encompass>`.
(Nothing clear in HTML 4 refs)

Answer (score 2):

The div tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.

The div tag is used to group block-elements to format them with CSS
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

The span tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.

The span tag provides no visual change by itself.

The span tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

A Div is a Division, since it divides things into groups.

My guess is that span is like a "Span of" something or group.

"the full extent of something from end to end; the amount of space that something covers."

Comment: If you answer the question itself more directly (why they were named this way, not what they do) then I'll accept as best answer.

Comment: I updated my original answer. Hope this helps. Also there isn't any html documentation that says the direct reasoning behind the name <span> but I put what I think the most probable reasoning was.

Answer (score 1):

Div is a block-level element that creates a line break to make separate containers or boxes within a page or document, hence its an abbreviation for 'division', whereas span is a generic container for inline elements and content that allow us to apply styles and other attributes to the content within the span element.